# Integrate: $\int e^{2\theta}\sin(3\theta)\ d\theta$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

> $$\int e^{2\theta}\sin(3\theta)\ d\theta$$
>   I don't know where to stop when it comes to questions such as this? Can you make me aware? I believe there was a possible prior person who answered the same question but they failed to indicate what the
>
> I was and in the larger scheme of things why there was no need to further integrate or utilize another method to integrate.  [image]

Comment: If you wish to ask for clarification of an answer on the other post, you can comment there. You can also see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116034/find-int-e2-theta-cdot-sin3-theta-d-theta?rq=1), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556613/evaluate-int-e2-theta-sin-3-theta-d-theta?rq=1), or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151358/integral-of-int-e2x-sin-3x-dx/155769#155769).

Comment: This is a standard example of integrating by parts and getting back to the function you started with.  You get $$\int = A - B\int$$ where it's the same integral both times.  So you rearrange it as $$\int+B\int = A$$ then as $$(1+B)\int = A$$ and finally as $$\int = \frac A {1+B}.$$